# command to enhance console lines with history

Tags: command-line

cmd utils such as sqllite don't have full flavoured console support. but I do remember there is something called `**wrap` which could wrap this console and enhance its capabilities with history, up/down etc...

unfortunately, I forget its name. anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about **rlwrap**.

> rlwrap runs the specified command, intercepting user input in order to provide readline's line editing, persistent history and completion.
>   rlwrap tries to be completely transparent - you (or your shell) shouldn't notice any difference between command and rlwrap command - except the added readline functionality, of course. This should even hold true when you are re-directing, piping and sending signals from and to command, or when command manipulates its terminal settings.  [rlwrap man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap)