# What should be done when a terminal application does not recognise some keyboard inputs?

Tags: bash, keyboard, bsd, games

I'm trying to play a very old [Star Trek BSD game](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/bsdgames/trek.6.en.html). It recognises characters that I type, but I occasionally make an error and want to use the arrow keys to correct it. This always fails. The pressing the left arrow on my keyboard makes me type `^[[D` and the other arrow keys are similar. I believe that many old packages behave like this.

What are the idiomatic solutions to this problem? Are them some old-school keyboard shortcuts that I have not thought to try? Or must I resort to manually modifying the game myself? It certainly seems to not expect Vi movements.

Comment: My bet is cursor moving was not coded in that game. Feel free to make a patch for using readline.

Comment: You could try `rlwrap` - see for example [command to enhance console lines with history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252964/command-to-enhance-console-lines-with-history)

Comment: @steeldriver That worked instantly and flawlessly. Feel free to post that as an answer.